# Is our project using Java EE / Java SE?

Tags: java, azul-zulu

Here is the information of our web development project.

```
Tool: Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers (i.e. Java EE IDE)
Libraries:
 - JRE System Library: zulu7.29.0.5-ca_jdk7.0.222-linux_x64 (JavaSE-1.7)
 - Other (e.g. Hibernate3, JbossAS, Struts-Portal, etc): JbossIDE
```

Is our project using Java EE or Java SE? I need to introduce what Java version that we are applying for our project but I have no idea how to find and explain. What Java EE version that we are applying for our project if we are using Java EE?

Comment: Java EE is a technology used to develop web / server applications.  Oracle's [Java EE at a Glance](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/java-ee-glance.html) describes the technology in more detail.  Java EE is built on top of Java SE.

Comment: Do you use another library besides JBossIDE? How do you run the project? Do you use an application server?

Comment: @dan1st I build the project and then get a WAR file. The WAR file will be deployed to an application server that uses Jboss.

Comment: You use JavaEE and JavaSE, then.

Answer (score 3):

"Java EE" (JEE) is a bunch of Java technologies regulated by specifications. JEE includes technologies like Enterprise JavaBeans, Java servlets, and JSP. If you're using any of these, you a probably "using JEE" in some sense.

However, "using JEE" isn't a particularly well-defined term. If my application uses servlets and runs on Tomcat than I'm probably "using JEE" to the extent that there is a JEE specification for servlets. But many people will use the term "using JEE" to mean, essentially, "running on a JEE-compliant application server".

I see "JBossAS" in the OP. I'm guessing that refers to JBoss Enterprise Application Platform (as it is now called). JBoss EAP is a JEE-compliant application server. If your application is hosted on EAP, it is probably a "JEE Application" in some sense. Different versions of EAP support different versions of the various applicable JEE specifications -- you'd have to look at the product documentation of your version to know which is appropriate in your case.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing we can say for sure about your project's Java SE / EE version requirements is that it is being built to run on a Java SE 7 platform.

The IDE you are using doesn't tell us anything.  (You can can use "Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers" to develop plain Java SE code ... if you want.)

The other technologies are Java EE relevant ... bit it is hard to discern a minimum Java EE version requirement.   Probably anything after Java EE 5 would be sufficient for Hibernate 3.  However, you probably should check the *specific versions* of *all* of the EE relevant libraries that you use for their Java EE platform requirements.